# How to iterate through neighbours in 2D coordinates?

Tags: python, php, loops, coordinates, pixel

In a 2D plane, I want to check the neighbouring points until meeting a condition. For example, take a red pixel in this image (`x,y`). I want to iterate to find the white pixel closest to the selected red pixel.

This is an updated image provided by [@Pranav Hosangadi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/843953/pranav-hosangadi)

[image]

My original code is now irrelevant.

A possible solution is to create an array sorted by the distance (given on the image). Then, by looping through this array, check when the condition is met (e.g., the point is white). However, this array will be indefinite and an overkill.

```
// $x,$y is a given point
$array = array(
'0,0'=>0,
'-1,0'=>1,
'-1,-1'=>1.4
);

asort($array)

foreach($array as $a=>$b){
$c=explode(',',$a);
$x2=$c[0]; // x-axis distance from the given point
$y2=$c[1]; // y-axis distance from the given point
$x3=$x+$x2;
$y3=$y+$y2;
if( $x3,$y3 point is white) { break;}
}

$closest_distance=$b;
```

Therefore, we need to build the loop without predefined `$array`.

Comment: Surrounding points can be either 4-connected or 8-connected, that is, neighbors are south, west, north and east, or also includes south-west, north-west, north-east and south-east. Which one do you use in your code?

Comment: @Stefan excuse my terminology. Neither neighbours nor surroundings, I just want the closest white pixel(s) to a given point (`x,y`).

Comment: You still need to define "closest". Can movement across your board be made diagonally?

Comment: Is the pixel one up and one to the right of your source pixel at a distance of 1, or sqrt(2) or 2 from your source pixel?

Comment: @El_Vanja yes, sure. The geometrically closest. The (x2-x,y2-y) vector.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi pixel up north and west are 1, and north-west is sqrt(2).

Comment: Which corner would be the starting point? Coordinate wise, the `[0, 0]`.

Comment: @El_Vanja it doesn't matter. For a given point, we should move like a spiral to hit the first white pixel.

Comment: We still have to address the pixels somehow. How do we know what the starting point is if we don't determine the root? You won't get the same results for [1, 3] relative to top left and relative to bottom left.

Comment: @El_Vanja why would it matter what pixel is (0, 0)? OP cares about distance _from pixel A to pixel B_, that doesn't change no matter where you decide (0, 0) is.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi Question author states _"I just want the closest white pixel(s)"_ - to me, this reads as literally give the pixels, as in their coordinates. If it is merely a question of distance, then the question should be edited to reflect this.

Comment: @Googlebot the problem with simply spiraling out from the start pixel is that the distance to the start pixel can decrease when you go one layer out. For example, in https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z1XFD.png, the pixel 4.2 away would come before the pixel 4.1 and 4 away.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi you are absolutely right. This is indeed the ultimate solution I am looking for, iterating by the actual distance from `x,y`.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi one possible solution is to create an array of points and sort it according to the distances quoted on your image. The problem is that the size of this array will be too large for an image with many pixels.

Comment: Can you please explicitly state what your desired return values are - distances or actual point coordinates?

Comment: Either way, I still stand by my argument that we need to determine the root square (pixel). If you take an `(x, y)` point as a parameter, you need to know relative to which corner those coordinates are. `(2, 3)` would land on a red pixel only relative to top left. Relative to other corners it would land on a white pixel.

Comment: You could use the [Bresenham circle-finding algorithm](https://arcade.makecode.com/graphics-math/bresenham-circle) and look for points that match increasing radii, but that still leaves gaps. For example in [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wXICs.png): points found by the algorithm for integer radii increasing from 6 through 15 are colored (not-purple), but some pixels are never selected.

Comment: @El_Vanja what you say makes sense -- unless you know the origin you can't answer the question "which point is the closest white point". I'm saying knowledge of the origin is immaterial to OP's question, which is _what algorithm can they use_. Pick your favorite point in the image as the origin. As long as your origin stays unchanged throughout the exercise, it doesn't affect the algorithm at all.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi Fair enough. I see now what you've been aiming at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a list of coordinate offsets ordered by their distance to the base point.  Then your search function would be much simpler to write:

```
maxRows,maxCols = 16,16
offsets = (offset for dx in range(maxRows) for dy in range(maxCols)
                  for offset in [(dx,dy),(dx,-dy),(-dx,dy),(-dx,-dy)])
offsets = sorted(offsets,key=lambda xy:xy[0]**2+xy[1]**2)[1:]


def closestPoint(pixels,row,col,value):
    for dx,dy in offsets:
        r,c = row+dy,col+dx
        if r not in range(len(pixels)): continue
        if c not in range(len(pixels[0])): continue
        if pixels[r][c] == value: return r,c
    return None,None
```

output:

```
bitmap = [    
[4, 2, 1, 2, 7, 3, 7, 2, 8, 7, 7, 8, 1, 7, 7, 6],
[6, 8, 3, 7, 1, 7, 8, 8, 8, 2, 4, 5, 8, 2, 5, 4],
[3, 2, 1, 6, 2, 7, 2, 2, 2, 2, 8, 2, 3, 5, 2, 7],
[8, 4, 4, 5, 2, 6, 7, 2, 6, 5, 6, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
[2, 6, 7, 2, 8, 6, 6, 8, 7, 6, 8, 6, 2, 8, 2, 8],
[6, 1, 7, 3, 7, 8, 8, 3, 0, 5, 6, 8, 4, 4, 5, 2],
[1, 5, 1, 7, 4, 5, 2, 2, 3, 7, 3, 3, 4, 2, 5, 4],
[1, 8, 5, 8, 1, 8, 2, 5, 4, 5, 4, 7, 2, 5, 7, 5],
[6, 6, 8, 6, 2, 6, 4, 1, 3, 4, 3, 6, 3, 6, 3, 7],
[6, 6, 5, 7, 3, 7, 3, 8, 1, 8, 2, 6, 3, 8, 2, 3],
[7, 5, 3, 1, 4, 3, 4, 3, 3, 5, 8, 5, 4, 4, 3, 3],
[2, 2, 1, 5, 1, 6, 6, 3, 8, 4, 1, 5, 2, 2, 1, 6],
[6, 2, 7, 1, 7, 4, 3, 5, 8, 6, 6, 3, 1, 2, 8, 5],
[1, 5, 1, 2, 2, 6, 3, 2, 3, 7, 4, 5, 6, 1, 8, 1],
[7, 6, 5, 2, 7, 2, 4, 8, 5, 1, 1, 4, 6, 1, 7, 7],
[2, 7, 3, 2, 1, 8, 6, 1, 6, 7, 4, 6, 7, 6, 2, 4]]

for p in range(1,9):
    print(p,closestPoint(bitmap,5,8,p))   

1 (8, 7)
2 (6, 7)
3 (6, 8)
4 (7, 8)
5 (5, 9)
6 (4, 9)
7 (4, 8)
8 (4, 7)
```

*Note that, if you are going to check this for every position in the matrix, it will be more efficient to create a matrix of distances using a proximity refinement algorithm.*

Going through offsets up to the maximum distance will skip 75% of the resulting positions. If you don't know the maximum size in advance or if you want to avoid useless position skipping in the offset loop, you can keep a dictionary of size-positions that maps to valid positions from a given base:

```
posByDist = dict()
def getPositionsByDistance(height,width,r,c):
    positions = posByDist.get((height,width,r,c),[])
    if not positions:
        offsets = ((dr*dr+dc*dc,dr,dc) for dx in range(height) 
                                       for dy in range(width)
                    for dr,dc in [(dx,dy),(dx,-dy),(-dx,dy),(-dx,-dy)]
                    if r+dr in range(height) and c+dc in range(width) )        
        positions = [(r+dr,c+dc) for _,dr,dc in sorted(offsets)]
        posByDist[height,width,r,c] = positions
    return positions

def closestPoint(pixels,row,col,value):
    h,w = len(pixels),len(pixels[0])
    return next(((r,c) for r,c in getPositionsByDistance(h,w,row,col)
                 if pixels[r][c] == value),(None,None))
```

This will only loop through valid positions and will dynamically create and reuse position maps as needed for those sizes and base positions that you actually encounter.

Answer (score 2):

Even though the question already has an accepted answer, I'd like to add my two bits (and a PHP implementation) with an algorithm that fulfills the additional request to return all the closest pixels.

A description of the algorithm (don't know if this has a name, I just tried to think of something): expand to the outer rim around the starting point and look for a match among those pixels. If none are found, move to the next rim and so on until a match is found or you've hit the border on all sides (no match in the entire image). A visualization might help understand; assume 0 as the starting point, then 1 is the first rim, 2 is the second, 3 is the third:

```
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|   |   | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|   |   | 3 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 3 |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|   |   | 3 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 3 |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|   |   | 3 | 2 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|   |   | 3 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 3 |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|   |   | 3 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 3 |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

To avoid having to handle a large number of elements when you reach far rims, instead of expanding to all the rim elements, we'd first expand to the closest pixels, then the ones that are the next closest and so on, by following these rules:

- The closest pixels in any rim are the ones where one coordinate remains unchanged and the other one is offset by the rim distance. For example, in rim 2, the closest ones are the ones where `dx = 0 && dy = +/-2` and where `dx = +/-2 && dy = 0`.
- The next closest pixels in any rim are those where the previously unchanged coordinate is now offset by 1, so in our example `dx = +/-1 && dy = +/-2` and `dx = +/-2 && dy = +/-1`.
- We keep increasing this variable offset by 1 until it equals the fixed offset (the rim distance, in our example that'd be 2).

Visual help for this gradual expansion (`S` is the starting point, `o` marks the pixels we fetch in the given step, `-` marks pixels we've already checked):

```
Step 1:
+---+---+---+---+---+
|   |   |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+
|   |   | o |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+
|   | o | S | o |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+
|   |   | o |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+
|   |   |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+

Step 2:
+---+---+---+---+---+
|   |   |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+
|   | o | - | o |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+
|   | - | S | - |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+
|   | o | - | o |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+
|   |   |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+

Step 3:
+---+---+---+---+---+
|   |   | o |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+
|   | - | - | - |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+
| o | - | S | - | o |
+---+---+---+---+---+
|   | - | - | - |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+
|   |   | o |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+

Step 4:
+---+---+---+---+---+
|   | o | - | o |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+
| o | - | - | - | o |
+---+---+---+---+---+
| - | - | S | - | - |
+---+---+---+---+---+
| o | - | - | - | o |
+---+---+---+---+---+
|   | o | - | o |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+

Step 5:
+---+---+---+---+---+
| o | - | - | - | o |
+---+---+---+---+---+
| - | - | - | - | - |
+---+---+---+---+---+
| - | - | S | - | - |
+---+---+---+---+---+
| - | - | - | - | - |
+---+---+---+---+---+
| o | - | - | - | o |
+---+---+---+---+---+
```

The pro of this algorithm is that it doesn't actually require any distance calculation and never handles more than 8 pixels at a time, no matter how far from the starting point we go. The con is that it is very iteration heavy. It favours finding close matches.

PHP implementation (it assumes upper left corner as the root `[0, 0]`):

```php
/**
 * Finds pixels with the lowest geometrical distance from given point (x, y) that match the criteria.
 */
function findGeometricallyClosestPixels(array $grid, int $x, int $y, string $criteria): array
{
    // if grid is empty or we're out of bounds
    if (empty($grid) || !isset($grid[$y]) || !isset($grid[0][$x])) {
        return [];
    }
    if ($grid[$y][$x] === $criteria) {
        return [[$x, $y]];
    }
    $result = [];
    for ($offset = 1; $offset < calculateMaximumOffset($grid, $x, $y); $offset++) {
        $result = array_merge($result, getClosestPixels($grid, $x, $y, $offset, $criteria));
        if (!empty($result)) {
            return $result;
        }
        for ($d = 1; $d <= $offset; $d++) {
            $result = array_merge($result, getPixelsForNegativeYOffsets($grid, $x, $y, $offset, $d, $criteria));
            $result = array_merge($result, getPixelsForPositiveYOffsets($grid, $x, $y, $offset, $d, $criteria));
            if (!empty($result)) {
                return $result;
            }
        }
    }

    return $result;
}

function getClosestPixels(array $grid, int $x, int $y, int $offset, string $criteria): array
{
    $result = [];
    if (isset($grid[$y][$x - $offset]) && $grid[$y][$x - $offset] === $criteria) {
        $result[] = [$x - $offset, $y];
    }
    if (isset($grid[$y][$x + $offset]) && $grid[$y][$x + $offset] === $criteria) {
        $result[] = [$x + $offset, $y];
    }
    if (isset($grid[$y - $offset][$x]) && $grid[$y - $offset][$x] === $criteria) {
        $result[] = [$x, $y - $offset];
    }
    if (isset($grid[$y + $offset][$x]) && $grid[$y + $offset][$x] === $criteria) {
        $result[] = [$x, $y + $offset];
    }

    return $result;
}

function getPixelsForNegativeYOffsets(array $grid, int $x, int $y, int $offset, int $d, string $criteria): array
{
    if (!isset($grid[$y - $d])) {
        return [];
    }
    $result = [];
    if (isset($grid[$y - $d][$x - $offset]) && $grid[$y - $d][$x - $offset] === $criteria) {
        $result[] = [$x - $offset, $y - $d];
    }
    if (isset($grid[$y - $d][$x + $offset]) && $grid[$y - $d][$x + $offset] === $criteria) {
        $result[] = [$x + $offset, $y - $d];
    }
    if (!isset($grid[$y - $offset])) {
        return $result;
    }
    if (isset($grid[$y - $offset][$x - $d]) && $grid[$y - $offset][$x - $d] === $criteria) {
        $result[] = [$x - $d, $y - $offset];
    }
    if (isset($grid[$y - $offset][$x + $d]) && $grid[$y - $offset][$x + $d] === $criteria) {
        $result[] = [$x + $d, $y - $offset];
    }

    return $result;
}

function getPixelsForPositiveYOffsets(array $grid, int $x, int $y, int $offset, int $d, string $criteria): array
{
    if (!isset($grid[$y + $d])) {
        return [];
    }
    $result = [];
    if (isset($grid[$y + $d][$x + $offset]) && $grid[$y + $d][$x + $offset] === $criteria) {
        $result[] = [$x + $offset, $y + $d];
    }
    if (isset($grid[$y + $d][$x - $offset]) && $grid[$y + $d][$x - $offset] === $criteria) {
        $result[] = [$x - $offset, $y + $d];
    }
    if (!isset($grid[$y + $offset])) {
        return $result;
    }
    if (isset($grid[$y + $offset][$x - $d]) && $grid[$y + $offset][$x - $d] === $criteria) {
        $result[] = [$x - $d, $y + $offset];
    }
    if (isset($grid[$y + $offset][$x + $d]) && $grid[$y + $offset][$x + $d] === $criteria) {
        $result[] = [$x + $d, $y + $offset];
    }

    return $result;
}

/**
 * Calculates maximum offset needed to reach the edge of given grid for given starting point.
 *
 * Lowest possible offset is right in the middle of the greater grid dimension (width or height). Since grid starts
 * at zero, if the point is positioned past the middle, then offset will equal its position. Otherwise, it will equal
 * greater dimension minus its position increased by one (to compensate for the fact that dimensions are measured
 * starting at 1, but positions start at 0).
 */
function calculateMaximumOffset(array $grid, int $x, int $y): int
{
    $gridHeight = count($grid);
    $gridWidth = count($grid[0]);
    if ($gridHeight >= $gridWidth) {
        $relevantDimensionValue = $gridHeight;
        $relevantCoordinateValue = $y;
    } else {
        $relevantDimensionValue = $gridWidth;
        $relevantCoordinateValue = $x;
    }
    $half = floor($relevantDimensionValue / 2);
    if ($relevantCoordinateValue >= $half) {
        return $relevantCoordinateValue;
    }
    return $relevantDimensionValue - ($relevantCoordinateValue + 1);
}
```

Here criteria is naive (a simple string we're matching against), in reality it'd probably do best as a callback, so any custom logic can be used on each grid element.

This implementation can probably be optimized, but I'll get around to it on a later occasion. I've only done some very basic optimizing.

The whole thing can be tested online [here](https://3v4l.org/H0OQc). I used an array representation of the heart image from the question, where `w` and `r` represent white and red pixels.

Comment: WOW, I am impressed by your answer!